# Avoid google map api call repetition

Tags: javascript

In my website I am loading google map via google map api call. I should call the google map api for first time page load.After the first time page loaded the next time I should avoid the api call to fetch map.

Please share your ideas to do.

Comment: @ rsvijay use `document.ready()`

Comment: You're going to have to make a call once per page load - how will it work if it only does it the first time. There will be nothing to load after that first time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to **not** have the map on your page **except** for the first time... but here you go.

Assuming you know enough JavaScript and AJAX to listen for events and do XHR's, just combine those two with `localStorage` (HTML5) to remember whether you already called the API before.

Concept:

1. Check if some flag (I'll call it `calledAPI`) is set in `localStorage`. If yes, do nothing.
2. Listen for a page `load` event.
3. Call the API via XHR.
4. In the XHR result function, set `calledAPI` in `localStorage`.